GluonFX materialized icons don't show up in the installed Android App
We are developing an app using GluonFX Mobile platform. We are at a point of successfully  installing the app on an Android Phone in developer mode.However,we don't see the Materialized Icons in the app reflected.We see X in the place of icons. Just to confirm we have an entry in the reflection-config.json for the Materialized Icons like this
{"name":"com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon","allDeclaredConstructors" : true,"allPublicConstructors" : true,"allDeclaredFields" : true,"allPublicFields" : true,"allDeclaredMethods" : true,"allPublicMethods" : true}

We are expecting the icons to be reflected in the Android app after installation as they appear on in Desktop run.
